# Procedure to get dates in between

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database that contains a `timesheet` table. This table is used to store roles for employees. Before I perform an insert I check to see of an employee has any preexisting roles in the selected days.

Here’s a stored procedure that returns the count of pre-existing roles

```
set @retVal=(select count(fk_RoleID) from dbo.TimesheetTable where 
(@startdate >=  CAST((
STR( YEAR( StartDate ) ) + '/' +
STR( MONTH( StartDate ) ) + '/' +
STR( DAY( StartDate ) )
)
AS DATE
))-- AND EndDate <= '2012-08-30')
and
(@enddate  <  CAST(
(
STR( YEAR( EndDate ) ) + '/' +
STR( MONTH( EndDate ) ) + '/' +
STR( DAY( EndDate ) )
)
AS DATE
))
and fk_PersonnelID=@personnelID)

return @retVal
```

The following are the records for one employee..

```
pk_ID  fk_PersonnelID  fk_RoleID  StartDate   EndDate     dateCreated
62     1               26         2012-10-01  2012-10-02  2012-10-25 15:55:12.940
81     1               20         2012-10-04  2012-10-06  2012-10-30 14:50:28.300
```

If I try to do an insert of where the start date is `2012-10-05` and end date is `2012-10-11`, the query fails to trap the `startdate` ..and the insert occurs

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You overlap test is incorrect.
The test should be "**both starts cometh before the opposite ends**".  Remember it, it's easy.

```
SELECT @retVal = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    select *
    from dbo.TimesheetTable
    where StartDate <= @EndDate
      and @StartDate <= EndDate
      and fk_PersonnelID=@personnelID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

To test for existence, switch to using EXISTS which will short-circuit and give you a result as soon as a result is found instead of COUNTing all matches.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse the StartDate and EndDate columns to get the results desired.

```
SELECT @retVal = COUNT(fk_RoleID)
FROM dbo.TimesheetTable AS tt
WHERE @startDate <= tt.EndDate
   AND @endDate >= tt.StartDate
   AND fk_PersonnelId = @personnelID;

return @retVal;
```

@retVal here would return a number greater than 0 for inputs that already have a schedule in the database.

Comment: Actually YYYY-MM-DD is NOT safe either. Try that with SET LANGUAGE FRENCH. In any case, your code is correct, there is no reason to parse these as strings, but you may need to eliminate time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are correct.  I should have specified default for US install.  I'll remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error in your date comparison inequalities because the date interval ranges I think you are attempting to match are overlapping - not properly contained - as your code seems to assume.

i.e. 10/4 - 10/6 strictly overlaps 10/5- 10/11 while your code implies that the parameter interval has to lie completely within the data row
s interval.

Comment: Seems you are correct but that's how the business logic is defined.Any thoughts on how I can capture when any of the date(s) overlap and when they don't?

Comment: @user1013666 The logic for any overlapping is that the start 1 has to be on or before end 2 and start 2 has to be on or before end 1.  This constraints there to be some overlap (with potential for proper containment).  Draw yourself a diagram if you have to convince yourself of the logic.  It's also symmetric with respect to the intervals as this property of the solution should also be self-evident.